# How to check if the bot is in the same channel as the user?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have been making a music discord bot and I wanted to check if the user is in the same voice channel as the bot.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```js
let voiceBot = client.voice.connections.channel;
const voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;

if(!voiceBot == voiceChannel)
  return msg.channel.send('you need to be in the same channel as the bot!')
```

Comment: Compare IDs instead of the objects.

Comment: But wait how can I get the ID of the bot channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`voice.connections`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientVoiceManager?scrollTo=connections) is a collection of connections, you can use the `.some()` method to iterate over these connections and check if any of the [connection's channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=channel) has the same `channel.id` as the `member.voice.channelID`.

The [`.some()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=some) method will return `true` if the member and the bot is in the same channel, `false` otherwise. So you can use it like this:

```js
const inSameChannel = client.voice.connections.some(
  (connection) => connection.channel.id === msg.member.voice.channelID
)

if (!inSameChannel)
  return msg.channel.send('You need to be in the same channel as the bot!')
```

Comment: Instead of iterating through `client.voice.connections` you could also just check `msg.guild.me.voice.channelID`. This will be much faster, especially if the bot is in multiple guilds.

Answer (score 1):

```
    client.voice.connections.find(i => i.channel.id === msg.member.voice.channel.id);
```

This will loop through the list of voice channels that the bot is currently in and check the channel id against the id of the message author's current voice channel. It will return the channel object, or `undefined` if nothing is found. You can use it inside of an if statement if you just want to check the ids:

```
    if (!client.voice.connections.find(i => i.channel.id === msg.member.voice.channel.id)) {
        console.log("The member isn't in a shared voice channel!");
    };
```

Or define it as a constant and get other information from it:

```
    const vc = client.voice.connections.find(i => i.channel.id === msg.member.voice.channel.id);

    if (vc) { //If the channel is valid
        console.log(`The voice channel id is: ${vc.channel.id}`);
    } else { //If the channel is undefined
        console.log("The member isn't in a shared voice channel!");
    };
```

Comment: But how can I check only if the bot was in a voice channel